# I can't perform most operations over npm, like downloading packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, backend

I want to learn backend using node.js on my computer but the npm command is not working. When I say it's not working, I mean I want to install a file and it doesn't give any errors but I can't use the packages.

```
npm i cors

up to date, audited 852 packages in 6s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Also it's packet.json

```
{
  "name": "deneme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "nodemon": "*"
  }
}
```

It doesn't show in the versions after installation

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.listen(4000 , () => {
    console.log('hello');
})
```

```
node deneme.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- C:\***\****\Desktop\deneme\deneme.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\***\****\Desktop\deneme\deneme.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

Tried Solutions:
-Tried different npm versions.
-Checked the PATH variable.
-Ran commands as administrator.
-Cleared the npm cache (I cant because its not working )

Does anyone know the reason for the issue and how to fix it?

I tried to download 'npm i cors' and other packages, but it didn't work. Something is blocking it, but I couldn't solve it. I already provided the details above

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Solution:

basically you error is about express module not found in your `node_modules`. just simply run command `npm i express nodemon --save`

### Another Solution:

First of all remove `package-lock.json` file from you root and remove or rename you `node_modules` folder.

Replace the content of `package.json` file with below:

```json
{
  "name": "deneme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^latest",
    "express": "^latest",
    "nodemon": "^latest"
  }
}
```

After replace run the `npm install` command at your project root path

That's it. Let me know if this will helpful to you.

Comment: ı tried but it didnt work.I also noticed that the node modules file is not being created.Additionally, when I followed your second instruction, I received this error: 'npm install
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^latest" of package "cors@^latest": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\***\****\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T19_53_45_796Z-debug-0.log'

Comment: run command in terminal at path of your project root. `npm install`

Comment: When I run "npm install", nothing happens. The node_modules folder is not created, only the package-lock.json file is generated. I cannot download anything, as I mentioned before.